Winforms custom user component returning errors when used after being packed as NuGet
I am trying to use a user control component I created and packed in NuGet and I get some errors. When I test the component in a test form within the same solution, by referencing the project, then it works correctly, when I pack it and install the NuGet package in a different solution and try to add it to a Windows Form project then I get this output:
[09:37:40.760285] warn: Could not find field, 'coreNotificationsWidgetControl1'.
[09:37:40.769545] fail: Request failures: DesignerHosts/CreateComponent.
                        Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsServerException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

                        For information on how to troubleshoot the designer refer to the guide at https://aka.ms/winforms/designer/troubleshooting.
[09:37:40.772546] fail: Exception: Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsServerException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
                           at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClient.<SendRequestAsync>d__49`1.MoveNext()
                        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                           at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
                           at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
                           at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Protocol.Endpoints.DesignToolsEndpoints.DesignerHostsImpl.CreateComponent(SessionId sessionId, TypeIdentity type, String name, NameValuePairs defaultValues)
                           at Microsoft.WinForms.DesignTools.Client.Toolbox.WinFormsToolboxItem.CreateComponentsCore(IDesignerHost host, IDictionary defaultValues)
                           at System.Drawing.Design.ToolboxItem.CreateComponents(IDesignerHost host, IDictionary defaultValues)
                           at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Designers.ComponentProxyDesigner.CreateTool(ToolboxItem tool, Nullable`1 location, Nullable`1 size, ObjectProxy toolboxSnapArgs)

                        For information on how to troubleshoot the designer refer to the guide at https://aka.ms/winforms/designer/troubleshooting.
[09:37:40.772546] fail: Exception message = Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsServerException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
                           at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClient.<SendRequestAsync>d__49`1.MoveNext()
                        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                           at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
                           at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
                           at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Protocol.Endpoints.DesignToolsEndpoints.DesignerHostsImpl.CreateComponent(SessionId sessionId, TypeIdentity type, String name, NameValuePairs defaultValues)
                           at Microsoft.WinForms.DesignTools.Client.Toolbox.WinFormsToolboxItem.CreateComponentsCore(IDesignerHost host, IDictionary defaultValues)
                           at System.Drawing.Design.ToolboxItem.CreateComponents(IDesignerHost host, IDictionary defaultValues)
                           at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Designers.ComponentProxyDesigner.CreateTool(ToolboxItem tool, Nullable`1 location, Nullable`1 size, ObjectProxy toolboxSnapArgs)

                        For information on how to troubleshoot the designer refer to the guide at https://aka.ms/winforms/designer/troubleshooting.
[09:37:46.353328] warn: Could not find field, 'coreNotificationsWidgetControl1'.

The code I have in the CoreNotificationsWidgetControl.cs is
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CoreNotifications_form
{
    public partial class CoreNotificationsWidgetControl: UserControl
    {
        public CoreNotificationsWidgetControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (!DesignMode)
            {
                Load += CoreNotificationsWidgetControl_Load;
            }
        }
    }
}

And in the CoreNotificationsWidgetControl.Designer.cs
using System;
using CoreComm_lib;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CoreNotifications_form
{
    partial class CoreNotificationsWidgetControl
    {
        private CoreLinkManager commManager;
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        private TabPage tabPage1;
        private TabPage tabPage2;
        private Button btnAcknowledge;
        private Button btnAcknowledgeAll;
        private TabControl tabControlNotifications;
        private DataGridView dataCurrentNotificationsGrid;
        private DataGridView dataHistoricalNotificationsGrid;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            commManager = new CoreLinkManager();

            tabPage1 = new TabPage();
            tabPage2 = new TabPage();
            btnAcknowledge = new Button();
            btnAcknowledgeAll = new Button();
            tabControlNotifications = new TabControl();
            dataCurrentNotificationsGrid = new DataGridView();
            dataHistoricalNotificationsGrid = new DataGridView();
            
            tabControlNotifications.SuspendLayout();
            tabPage1.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)dataCurrentNotificationsGrid).BeginInit();
            tabPage2.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)dataHistoricalNotificationsGrid).BeginInit();
            SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // tabControlNotifications
            // 
            tabControlNotifications.Controls.Add(tabPage1);
            tabControlNotifications.Controls.Add(tabPage2);
            tabControlNotifications.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            tabControlNotifications.Name = "tabControlNotifications";
            tabControlNotifications.SelectedIndex = 0;
            tabControlNotifications.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(951, 372);
            tabControlNotifications.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // tabPage1
            // 
            tabPage1.Controls.Add(dataCurrentNotificationsGrid);
            tabPage1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 29);
            tabPage1.Name = "tabPage1";
            tabPage1.Padding = new Padding(3);
            tabPage1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(943, 339);
            tabPage1.TabIndex = 0;
            tabPage1.Text = "Current Notifications";
            tabPage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // dataCurrentNotificationsGrid
            // 
            dataCurrentNotificationsGrid.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            dataCurrentNotificationsGrid.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 6);
            dataCurrentNotificationsGrid.Name = "dataCurrentNotificationsGrid";
            dataCurrentNotificationsGrid.RowHeadersWidth = 51;
            dataCurrentNotificationsGrid.RowTemplate.Height = 24;
            dataCurrentNotificationsGrid.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(931, 327);
            dataCurrentNotificationsGrid.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // tabPage2
            // 
            tabPage2.Controls.Add(dataHistoricalNotificationsGrid);
            tabPage2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 29);
            tabPage2.Name = "tabPage2";
            tabPage2.Padding = new Padding(3);
            tabPage2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(943, 339);
            tabPage2.TabIndex = 1;
            tabPage2.Text = "Historical Notifications";
            tabPage2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // dataHistoricalNotificationsGrid
            // 
            dataHistoricalNotificationsGrid.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            dataHistoricalNotificationsGrid.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 6);
            dataHistoricalNotificationsGrid.Name = "dataHistoricalNotificationsGrid";
            dataHistoricalNotificationsGrid.RowHeadersWidth = 51;
            dataHistoricalNotificationsGrid.RowTemplate.Height = 24;
            dataHistoricalNotificationsGrid.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(931, 327);
            dataHistoricalNotificationsGrid.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // btnAcknowledge
            // 
            btnAcknowledge.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(967, 41);
            btnAcknowledge.Name = "btnAcknowledge";
            btnAcknowledge.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(137, 42);
            btnAcknowledge.TabIndex = 1;
            btnAcknowledge.Text = "Acknowledge";
            btnAcknowledge.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            btnAcknowledge.Click += BtnAcknowledge_Click;
            // 
            // btnAcknowledgeAll
            // 
            btnAcknowledgeAll.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(967, 102);
            btnAcknowledgeAll.Name = "btnAcknowledgeAll";
            btnAcknowledgeAll.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(137, 42);
            btnAcknowledgeAll.TabIndex = 2;
            btnAcknowledgeAll.Text = "Acknowledge All";
            btnAcknowledgeAll.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            btnAcknowledgeAll.Click += BtnAcknowledgeAll_Click;
            // 
            // CoreNotificationsWidgetControl
            // 
            AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 20F);
            AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
            Controls.Add(btnAcknowledge);
            Controls.Add(btnAcknowledgeAll);
            Controls.Add(tabControlNotifications);
            Name = "CoreNotificationsWidgetControl";
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1114, 390);
            Load += CoreNotificationsWidgetControl_Load;
            tabControlNotifications.ResumeLayout(false);
            tabPage1.ResumeLayout(false);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)dataCurrentNotificationsGrid).EndInit();
            tabPage2.ResumeLayout(false);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)dataHistoricalNotificationsGrid).EndInit();
            ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        #endregion

        private void CoreNotificationsWidgetControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!DesignMode)
            {
                InitializeDataGridView();
                PopulateDataGridView();
                InitializeHistoricalDataGridView();
                PopulateHistoricalDataGridView();
            }
        }

        private void InitializeDataGridView()
        {
            if (dataCurrentNotificationsGrid == null)
                return;

            dataCurrentNotificationsGrid.Columns.Clear();

            // Add columns with specific AutoSizeMode settings
            var idColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Id", HeaderText = "ID", AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells };
            var labelColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Label", HeaderText = "Label", AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells };
            var messageColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Message", HeaderText = "Message", AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill };
            var severityColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Severity", HeaderText = "Severity", AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells };
            var statusColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Status", HeaderText = "Status", AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells };
            var sourceColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Source", HeaderText = "Source", AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells };
            var timestampColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Timestamp", HeaderText = "Timestamp", AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells };

            // Add columns to the DataGridView
            dataCurrentNotificationsGrid.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[]
            {
                idColumn,
                labelColumn,
                messageColumn,
                severityColumn,
                statusColumn,
                sourceColumn,
                timestampColumn
            });
        }

        private void InitializeHistoricalDataGridView()
        {
            if (dataHistoricalNotificationsGrid == null)
                return;

            dataHistoricalNotificationsGrid.Columns.Clear();

            // Add columns with specific AutoSizeMode settings
            var idColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Id", HeaderText = "ID", AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells };
            var labelColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Label", HeaderText = "Label", AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells };
            var messageColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Message", HeaderText = "Message", AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill };
            var severityColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Severity", HeaderText = "Severity", AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells };
            var statusColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Status", HeaderText = "Status", AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells };
            var sourceColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Source", HeaderText = "Source", AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells };
            var timestampColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Timestamp", HeaderText = "Timestamp", AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells };

            // Add columns to the DataGridView
            dataHistoricalNotificationsGrid.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[]
            {
                idColumn,
                labelColumn,
                messageColumn,
                severityColumn,
                statusColumn,
                sourceColumn,
                timestampColumn
            });
        }

        public void PopulateDataGridView()
        {
            if (commManager == null || dataCurrentNotificationsGrid == null)
                return;

            // Clear existing rows to avoid duplicates
            dataCurrentNotificationsGrid.Rows.Clear();

            var notifications = commManager.AllNotifications;
            foreach (var notification in notifications)
            {
                dataCurrentNotificationsGrid.Rows.Add(
                    notification.Id,
                    notification.Label,
                    notification.Message,
                    notification.Severity,
                    notification.Status,
                    notification.Source,
                    notification.FormattedTimestamp
                );
            }

            dataCurrentNotificationsGrid.Sort(dataCurrentNotificationsGrid.Columns["Timestamp"], System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        }

        public void PopulateHistoricalDataGridView()
        {
            if (commManager == null || dataHistoricalNotificationsGrid == null)
                return;

            // Clear existing rows to avoid duplicates
            dataHistoricalNotificationsGrid.Rows.Clear();

            var historicalNotifications = commManager.HistoricalNotifications;
            foreach (var notification in historicalNotifications)
            {
                dataHistoricalNotificationsGrid.Rows.Add(
                    notification.Id,
                    notification.Label,
                    notification.Message,
                    notification.Severity,
                    notification.Status,
                    notification.Source,
                    notification.FormattedTimestamp
                );
            }
        }

        public void SetCommManager(CoreLinkManager manager)
        {
            commManager = manager;
        }

        private void BtnAcknowledge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataCurrentNotificationsGrid.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                var selectedRow = dataCurrentNotificationsGrid.SelectedRows[0];
                var notificationId = selectedRow.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString();
                var notificationSource = selectedRow.Cells["Source"].Value.ToString();

                var notification = commManager.AllNotifications.Find(n => n.Id == notificationId && n.Source == notificationSource);
                if (notification != null)
                {
                    commManager.AcknowledgeNotification(notification);
                    PopulateDataGridView();
                    PopulateHistoricalDataGridView();
                }
            }
        }

        private void BtnAcknowledgeAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            commManager.AcknowledgeAllNotifications();
            PopulateDataGridView();
            PopulateHistoricalDataGridView();
        }
    }
}

I am not sure what to check to understand why I am getting this errors or which object reference is not set.

Do you actually have user code in the Designer file of this UC? If that's the case, move it elsewhere (high priority) -- You cannot check DesignMode in the Constructor of a component. You can do that in OnHandleCreated() (I see you're doing it again in Load <- you should just override OnLoad(), though, not add an event handler in your own class) -- What is calling SetCommManager()? -- There are probably missing parts that don't allow to determine what's going on there; fix the code and, IMO, repost something after you have removed parts not immediately relevant to the question

@Jimi, sorry I do not understand what you mean with your comment, this is the first time I use dotNet and I am trying to create some component, the code I showed is exactly as I have it in my project and it works when I reference the project. I do not know what you mean by move the user code from the Designer file to somewhere else? Which user code? I think all the code displayed is relevant to the question so I am not sure what you mean.

The file that contains System.ComponentModel.IContainer and the default Dispose() method, that's the Designer file. Don't add any code there -- Remove what you added after InitializeComponent() (the DesingMode check;, also, you have already added a handler to the Load event in the UC designer) -- The exception is saying that the instance of the UC, added to Form, cannot be found (it's probably null or the Control has not been created at all) -- I have no idea how you have packaged that Control, or the CoreComm_lib, and when this exception is generated

You added code to the designer.cs file that is uncommon and not good practise. And all you put there does not need to be there it can easily life in the standard file without the designer postfix. Designer file for the designer the other file of the control for you to change. Said that it does not fell like its the source of the problem. If you get design time exception you might simply want to debug that. You can debug  Visual Studio with Visual Studio to debug adding the control to a form.
